# Excel referencing column and row in a formula in another cell

Tags: excel-formula

Is it possible to create a formula for something like this:

1. Say in cell A1 the formula is =B10
2. In A2, I need a formula =B(10+5), or basically the row reference from cell A1 plus 5

So if A1=C23 then A2=C28 or if A1=D30 then A2=D35 and so on.

Comment: it is possible if that's what you wanna know

Comment: Well, I would like to know know how create that formula. If you could show me, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way to do it:

```
=INDIRECT((MID(FORMULATEXT(A1),FIND("=",FORMULATEXT(A1))+1,1)&(MID(FORMULATEXT(A1),FIND("=",FORMULATEXT(A1))+2,1000))+5))
```

**UPDATE**
***here is the [demo worksheet downloadable](https://www.dropbox.com/s/epkqpbvjp954ygw/convert_indirect_formula.xlsx?dl=0)***

**SECOND UPDATE**

here is the formula to replace the column reference:

```
=INDIRECT((REPLACE(MID(FORMULATEXT(A1),FIND("=",FORMULATEXT(A1))+1,1),1,1,"D"))&(MID(FORMULATEXT(A1),FIND("=",FORMULATEXT(A1))+2,1000))+5)
```

Comment: Fyi, `FORMULATEXT` is new in Excel 2013, not available in earlier versions

Comment: Thanks! I only have my mac with me at the moment so I can't try it but I would later. So what if I want to change the column. For example, if A1=C23 then A2=D28 or if A1=B30 then A2=D35. Let's say the column will always be fixed to D in the A2 cell's formula. I assume you need to replace the first MID() function with something else. Could you write an example of it?

Comment: @guear: do you want it to change always to **D**? by the way, if the my answer meets the requirements of your question, then please accept it.

Comment: @AHC thanks AHC, I tried the worksheet on 2013 excel and it works!

Comment: @chrisneilsen thanks, I tried your solution but it gave me #REF! error. Your solution might be useful on my computers with older excel